# Portal Cautivo mediante IPTABLES

Tags: php, linux, iptables

Amigos, que tal. Nuevamente haciendo una consulta a traves de vuestro foro.
Estoy intentando realizar un portal cautivo simple con iptables y PHP sin embargo no consigo hacer que funcione. Les explcio, actualmente tengo un servidor en modo bridge, y en este redirecciono el trafico que va hacia el puerto 80 hacia el puerto 8081 de otro servidor, quien muestra una pagina y da la opcion de continuar para que el cliente siga su navegacion. Esto ultimo no me funciona. Al redireccionar recibo en un index.html que es el siguiente::

```
    <?php
    //VARIABLES CONEXION BD
    $host = "dbserver";
$user = "usuariodb";
$pwd = "passworddb";
$db="basededatos";
$ipserv= "127.0.0.1:8081";

$dom = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
$rest = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$url_completa = "http://" . $dom . $rest; 

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')  {
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

//CONEXION A BASE DE DATOS
$link = mysql_connect( $host, $user, $pwd ) or die( "Error al conectar" . mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("La base de datos no existe");
//Consulta Base de datos para obtener MAC en base a la IP
$sql = "select mac from clie left join clientes ON cr_clid = id where iprouter = '".$ip_address."'";
echo "consulta $sql \n";

//GUARDANDO VARIABLES Y RESULTADOS CONSULTA
$mac=mysql_query($sql);

$var1 = "sudo iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -m mac --mac-source ".$mac." -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination ".$ipserv."";
shell_exec($var1);

  header("Location: '".$url_completa."'");
} else {
?>
<html>
<body style="padding: 0em 1em;">
    <h1 style="overflow: hidden;"><img style="float:right;">&iexcl;Aviso de Corte! </h1>
    <p>Si estas viendo esto, es debido a que tu cuenta esta proxima a vencer, evita la suspension de tu servicio cancelando anticipadamente, asi evitaras perder acceso a tu informacion y cobros por corte y reposicion. </p>
   <form method="POST">
      <p>Gracias por preferirnos para continuar con su navegacion normalmente por favor pulse en el boton  
         <input type="submit" value="Continuar" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>";
<?php
}
?>
```

Al presionar continuar no se realiza ninguna accion, y deberia al menos redireccionar al dominio que intentaba navegar.
Puede alguien darme una mano?

Answer (score 1):

1.- debería ser un archivo con extension php y no .html

2.- en

```
//GUARDANDO VARIABLES Y RESULTADOS CONSULTA
$mac=mysql_query($sql);
```

$mac es un resulset, debes extraer el valor del campo "mac", por ejemplo

```
//GUARDANDO VARIABLES Y RESULTADOS CONSULTA
$resultado=mysql_query($sql);
$fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado);
$mac = $fila["mac"];
```

3.- en:

```
$var1 = "sudo iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -m mac --mac-source ".$mac." -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination ".$ipserv."";
```

por que es -D ? no estas agregando una regla ( -A) ?

4.- ¿apache es sudoer?

Comment: hola, gracias por responder. en que cambia si el index es extension html o php?
hasta ahora, lo resuelve y muestra el contenido, en que podria afectar?
Respecto a la base de datos, y el varlor MAC, ya fue corregido, y el iptables es -D puesto que al presionar continuar, elimina la regla ya creada por otra instancia en el servidor.